# Порядок вывода блоков при изменении разрешения

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Подскажите с решением задачи.
Есть столбцы с городами в алфавитном порядке - [скрин шаблона](https://prnt.sc/q4ekep)
При изменении разрешения, правый блок переносится вниз и тогда получается буква "Д", под столбцом "А". А надо чтобы колонка с буквой "Б" ушла под "А" и дальше порядок сохранился - [скрин шаблона](http://prntscr.com/q5x668). Можно выводить в столбце фиксированное количество городов, но они добавляются динамически и сколько на какую букву их будет неизвестно.

Comment: Это вполне нормальное поведение. Можете использовать flex и играть свойством order, либо ставить брейкпойнты и задавать ширину блокам так, чтобы они вставали в нужном порядке. Не вижу в чем проблема

Comment: я пробовал при помощи order но  при динамическом добавлении часть городов на букву А может находится в нескольких столбцах и опять проблема получается

Comment: А почему часть городов на букву А может находится в нескольких столбцах? Сделайте так, чтобы каждой букве соответствовал только один столбец

Comment: хотят что-то типа того [ссылка]http://prntscr.com/q5y7g3[ссылка]

Comment: Ну, по Вашей ссылке я вижу, что города на М в двух столбцах, на С - тоже в двух. Там просто список, никаких блоков, которые бы уходили друг под друга.

Comment: Видимо я просто туплю. Т.е. можно просто список сделать?

Comment: Вот как у меня получается (в хедере при клике на минск и там все города) - [ссылка]http://test3.dtraduga.vh66.hosterby.com/[ссылка] - а надо чтобы хотябы одно под другое шло по алфавиту

Comment: ссылка test3 не открывается

Comment: странно -  а так http://test3.dtraduga.vh66.hosterby.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в комментах мы с Вами выяснили, что можно сделать обычным списком, то вот Вам примерный рабочий вариант. Если надо на чистом css, то можно "костылить" с медиа-запросами (на разные размеры экрана задавать разное количество колонок).

Я сделал с помощью jQuery (количество колонок меняется динамически при ресайзе или повороте экрана):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function setColumnCount(){ //создаём функцию, которая будет задавать количество колонок
    let labelWidth = 0; //переменная, в которую запишем самый длинный город
    $('label').each(function(){ //в цикле проходим по городам
      if($(this).outerWidth() > labelWidth){
        labelWidth = $(this).outerWidth(); //находим самый длинный
      }
    });
    let wrapWidth = $('.wrapper').outerWidth(); //находим длину блока-обёртки
    $('.wrapper').css('column-count', Math.floor(wrapWidth/(labelWidth))); //задаём количество колонок
  }
  
  setColumnCount(); //запускаем функцию при загрузке
  
  $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function(){ 
    setColumnCount(); //запускаем функцию при ресайзе или повороте экрана
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 02</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 003</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 4</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 05</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 006</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 7</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 08</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 9</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 10</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 011</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 0012</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 13</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 014</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 00015</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 016</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 17</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 0018</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 19</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 020</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 21</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 22</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 00023</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 24</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 0025</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 026</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 27</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 28</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 0029</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="city" />Город 30</label></li>
</ul>
```